# Set toolbar button toggle state wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython

the question looks quite basic, but I cannot manage to set the state of the toolbar toggle button to not toggled, without breaking it.

I create the toolbar toggle button using

```
button = toolbar.AddLabelTool(..., kind=wx.ITEM_CHECK)
```

Then I check the its state using

```
button.IsToggled()
```

These all work fine. The problem comes when I want to manually un-toggle the button.

I have tried

```
button.SetToggle(False)
```

which does un-toggle it but seems to break the behaviour of the button - seems to make the check above always return False.

```
button.IsToggled = False
```

and

```
toolbar.ToggleTool(11, False)
```

don't seem to work.

Any ideas ? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`toolbar.AddLabelTool(..., kind=wx.ITEM_CHECK)` I believe is deprecated.
Use `toolbar.AddCheckTool(..., kind=wx.ITEM_CHECK)` instead.
Then use `GetToolState()` to return the state of the tool.
Documented here [Toolbar](https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.ToolBar.html#wx.ToolBar.GetToolState)

Comment: link is broken, new link: https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.ToolBar.html?highlight=toolbar#wx.ToolBar.AddCheckTool

Comment: @user2682863 Old link replaced with a working one. Cheers!